# Tweepy Attribute Error

Tags: python, tweepy

I am new to python and tweepy and get an error message I cannot really understand:

```
import json
from tweepy import Cursor
from twitter_client import get_twitter_client

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = get_twitter_client()

    with open('home_timeline.jsonl', 'w') as f:
        for page in Cursor(client.home_timeline, count=200).pages(4):
            for status in page:
                f.write(json.dumps(status._json)+"\n")
```

Running this code gives the following error-messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitter_get_user_timeline.py", line 10, in <module>
    for page in Cursor(client.home_timeline, count=200).pages(4):
  File "/home/projects/webscraping/testEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tweepy/cursor.py", line 49, in __next__
    return self.next()
  File "/home/projects/webscraping/testEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tweepy/cursor.py", line 108, in next
    data = self.method(max_id=self.max_id, parser=RawParser(), *self.args, **self.kargs)
  File "/home/projects/webscraping/testEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 239, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/home/projects/webscraping/testEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 174, in execute
    auth = self.api.auth.apply_auth()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'apply_auth'
```

Since this goes really deep into Tweepy, I cannot really understand where my mistake in the code lies (and the code is from the book: Marco Bonzanini: "Mastering Social Media Mining with Python"). Does anybody have an idea what's going wrong here?

The authentification is done in the twitter_client that is imported. The code there is:

```
import os
import sys
from tweepy import API
from tweepy import OAuthHandler

def get_twitter_auth():
    """Setup Twitter authentication.
      Return: tweepy.OAuthHandler object
    """
    try:
        consumer_key = os.environ['TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY']
        consumer_secret = os.environ['TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET']
        access_token = os.environ['TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN']
        access_secret = os.environ['TWITTER_ACESS_SECRET']

    except KeyError:
        sys.stderr.write("TWITER_* environment variables not set\n")
        sys.exit(1)
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
    return auth

def get_twitter_client():
    """Setup Twitter API client

     Return: tweepy.API object
     """
    auth = get_twitter_auth
    client = API(auth)
    return client
```

Thanks a lot for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In second file, function `get_twitter_client`, line `auth = get_twitter_auth`.

You are saving the `get_twitter_auth`**function** in `auth` and not the **returned value**.

Fix it with `auth = get_twitter_auth()`

Comment: I cannot upvote b/c my reputation is too low here, and I can only accept an answer 15 minutes after my own question - but no worries, I will validate it then and upvote as soon as it is possible here :)

Comment: Nah, it's really not important, the only goal is to help, upvote are just here to troll my coworkers